# subtract values from different lines

Tags: python-3.x

I have a csv file that I am reading in, I have a column of numerical strings and I'm trying to get the difference between the two subsequent rows.  The numbers were in depths with "ft" following the values (ex. 4.23ft), I was able to get rid of the "ft" (ex. 4.230), but can't figure out how to assign the values so I can do the math.

```
    depth = float(depth)
    rate=0
    '''Need to find a way to subtract next line from current line to find 
    rate of change over 15 minute period'''
    for i, data in enumerate(depth):
        d1=i
        d2=i+1
        while rate == 0:
            rate = d1-d2                 
            print(rate)
```

This gives me a TypeError of " 'float' object is not iterable".
when I have the "depth = float(depth)" line commented out, I only get -1 values, which I understand the issue there.

[first few lines of raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edOsR.png)
[first few lines of result data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwLwL.png)

second row first value minus second value equals first value in third row.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html

Comment: What is in `depth` before you run this code? ([Edit] this into your question, please. "My data" or "some line from the csv" does not help us help you.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already stripped the "ft" part from your column and assuming you have converted the remaining part of the string to float type, I will jump into the next part directly.

If I understand what you want to achieve correctly, you can also use [pandas.DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['D1'] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Your D1 the value from current row, D2 will be the column from D1 by performing shift operation.

```
df['D2'] = df['D1'].shift(-1)
```

Your dataframe will now look like:

```
    D1   D2
0  1.0  2.0
1  2.0  3.0
2  3.0  4.0
3  4.0  5.0
4  5.0  NaN
```

In short, you have the values from the subsequent row of the current row into a new column. You can now perform subtraction/difference operation between the two columns as usual. For example:

```
df['D3'] = df['D1'] - df['D2']
```

or

```
df['D3'] = df['D1'].sub(df['D2'])
```

Comment: tried your suggestion, now I'm getting "Series([], dtype: float64)"
        depth = float(depth)
        df=pd.DataFrame()
        df['d1']=depth
        df['d2']=df['d1'].shift(-1)
        df['rate'] = df['d1']-df['d2']                
        print(depth,d1,d2,rate)

output from the print line:
4.23 4 5 Series([], dtype: float64)

Comment: fixed the "Series([], dtype: float64)" but the d1 value where I'm getting 4 should match the depth value where I have 4.23, I'm wondering if it is truncating, but I still don't know why the d2 value is popping up as 5 when it should be the next line down, which happens to also be a 4.23

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Could you please post your raw dataframe and final expected dataframe by editing the question? It is hard to comprehend from the comments.

Comment: I also apologize for the late response, I believe I added the information you requested, and if it isn't, I apologize for that too and request the definition of a dataframe.